# Appending values to DataSet in Apache Flink

Tags: apache-flink

I am currently writing an (simple) analytisis code to sum time connected powerreadings. With the data being assumingly raw (e.g. disturbances from the measuring device have not been calculated out) I have to account for disturbances by calculation the mean of the first one thousand samples. The calculation of the mean itself is not a problem. I only am unsure of how to generate the appropriate DataSet.
For now it looks about like this:

```
DataSet<Tupel2<long,double>>Gyrotron_1=ECRH.includeFields('11000000000'); // obviously the line to declare the first gyrotron, continues for the next ten lines, assuming separattion of not occupied space
        DataSet<Tupel2<long,double>>Gyrotron_2=ECRH.includeFields('10100000000');
        DataSet<Tupel2<long,double>>Gyrotron_3=ECRH.includeFields('10010000000');
        DataSet<Tupel2<long,double>>Gyrotron_4=ECRH.includeFields('10001000000');
        DataSet<Tupel2<long,double>>Gyrotron_5=ECRH.includeFields('10000100000');
        DataSet<Tupel2<long,double>>Gyrotron_6=ECRH.includeFields('10000010000');
        DataSet<Tupel2<long,double>>Gyrotron_7=ECRH.includeFields('10000001000');
        DataSet<Tupel2<long,double>>Gyrotron_8=ECRH.includeFields('10000000100');
        DataSet<Tupel2<long,double>>Gyrotron_9=ECRH.includeFields('10000000010');
        DataSet<Tupel2<long,double>>Gyrotron_10=ECRH.includeFields('10000000001');
        for (int=1,i<=10;i++) {
            DataSet<double> offset=Gyroton_'+i+'.groupBy(1).first(1000).sum()/1000;
        }
```

It's the part in the for-loop I'm unsure of. Does anybody know if it is possible to append values to  DataSets and if so how?
In case of doubt, I could always put the values into an array but I do not know if that is the wise thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

This code will not work for many reasons. I'd recommend looking into the fundamentals of Java and the basic data structures and also in [Flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.10/dev/batch/).

It's really hard to understand what you actually try to achieve but this is the closest that I came up with

```
    String[] codes = { "11000000000", ..., "10000000001" };
    DataSet<Tuple2<Long, Double>> result = env.fromElements();
    for (final String code : codes) {
        DataSet<Tuple2<Long, Double>> codeResult = ECRH.includeFields(code)
            .groupBy(1)
            .first(1000)
            .sum(0)
            .map(sum -> new Tuple2<>(sum.f0, sum.f1 / 1000d));
        result = codeResult.union(result);
    }
    result.print();
```

But please take the time and understand the basics before delving deeper. I also recommend to use an IDE like IntelliJ that would point to at least 6 issues in your code.

Comment: You mind explaining me the code within the map function? I'm not acquianted to lambda expressions.